# Make Clickable Box Some This Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Now i working for a Chat system!
Now I want show a box when click on USERNAME!
and hide box when click else ever! (anywhere but box!)
Same Help box in this site nav menu

[Screen Shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0z6r.png)

[Screen Shot 2](http://forums.ipbfarsi.ir/uploads/post-2631-0-61098600-1410991694.png)

I Want show this box with call a function and send some value to function...

same this:  showbox(e,userid,username);

e= mouse x,y ...

Thanks!

Comment: I call show function and send username and userid to function and show box on mouse x,y position.   and also add on body click hide box. but when i click in username for open box also clicked in body! mean in 1milisecond box show and very fast hide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could show the menu box by using **onclick** event in username control.

```
$('body').click(function(e) {   
    // hide your menu
});
```

In this jquery is execute when ever user click anywhere in the body.